# TMonthCalendar & Delphi Styles (Delphi XE2)

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, vcl-styles

TMontCalendar seems to be a Windows wrapper so it can't be affected by the new VCL Styles, do you know a solution for it ?

Comment: Until RRUZ gives you the solution you might want to read about [vcl-styles-and-owner-draw](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2012/03/14/vcl-styles-and-owner-draw/). In particular [TStyleHook](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Themes.TStyleHook).

Comment: Here is someone who hacked TWebBrowser to use VCL styles: http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2012/03/20/delphi-vcl-styles-and-twebbrowser-source-code-released/

Comment: And this may also help http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2012/03/14/vcl-styles-and-owner-draw/

Comment: @all : I saw these (excellent) posts, but I would know if htere was a more elegant & simple solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`TMonthCalendar`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TMonthCalendar) is wrapper for the [MONTHCAL_CLASS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775491%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and  as far i know this control doesn't support owner draw, but provides the [`CalColors`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TMonthCalendar.CalColors) property which allow you to set the colors of the elements of the calendar, but this property only works when the themes is not enabled. So first you must call the [SetWindowTheme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759827%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to disable the themes in the calendar and then you can set the colors to match with the vcl styles.

Something like this

```
uses
  Vcl.Styles,
  Vcl.Themes,
  uxTheme;

Procedure SetVclStylesColorsCalendar( MonthCalendar: TMonthCalendar);
Var
  LTextColor, LBackColor : TColor;
begin
   uxTheme.SetWindowTheme(MonthCalendar.Handle, '', '');//disable themes in the calendar
   MonthCalendar.AutoSize:=True;//remove border

   //get the vcl styles colors
   LTextColor:=StyleServices.GetSystemColor(clWindowText);
   LBackColor:=StyleServices.GetSystemColor(clWindow);

   //set the colors of the calendar
   MonthCalendar.CalColors.BackColor:=LBackColor;
   MonthCalendar.CalColors.MonthBackColor:=LBackColor;
   MonthCalendar.CalColors.TextColor:=LTextColor;
   MonthCalendar.CalColors.TitleBackColor:=LBackColor;
   MonthCalendar.CalColors.TitleTextColor:=LTextColor;
   MonthCalendar.CalColors.TrailingTextColor:=LTextColor;
end;
```

And the result will be this

[image]
[image]

Comment: OK I was more or less on the same. But your's is really more clear & smart !