# Set Back Color On DateTime Picker

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-xe3

How can I make Back Color feature work on the TDateTimePicker.  I would just like to set the backbround color of the control.

Answer (score 2):

The date time picker control, when shown in a themed app, has colours that are determined by the theme. You cannot control the colours used by the themed paint.

You could disable themes for the control using `SetWindowTheme` and achieve what you want. Here is an example using an interposer class:

```
type
  TDateTimePicker = class(Vcl.ComCtrls.TDateTimePicker)
  protected
    procedure CreateWnd; override;
    procedure CNNotify(var Message: TWMNotifyDT); message CN_NOTIFY;
  end;

procedure TDateTimePicker.CreateWnd;
begin
  inherited;
  SetWindowTheme(WindowHandle, '', '');
  CalColors.BackColor := clFuchsia;
  CalColors.MonthBackColor := clFuchsia;
  CalColors.TitleBackColor := clFuchsia;
end;

procedure TDateTimePicker.CNNotify(var Message: TWMNotifyDT);
var
  DropDownHandle: HWND;
begin
  inherited;
  case Message.NMHdr.code of
  DTN_DROPDOWN:
    begin
      DropDownHandle := Perform(DTM_GETMONTHCAL, 0, 0);
      SetWindowTheme(DropDownHandle, '', '');
    end;
  end;
end;
```

[image]

Note that we also need to disable themes on the date/time picker's child month calendar control. That's because the calendar is drawn using a separate window from the main control.

You could choose not to disable themes for the main control, in which case the control looks like this:

[image]

But I feel that looks a little odd.

@RRUZ wrote an excellent answer on the closely associated topic of VCL styles for the date time picker: [Style properties for TDateTimePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335310/style-properties-for-tdatetimepicker/10338248#10338248)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Win32 API SendMessage() function, or the TDateTimePicker's own `Perform()` method, to send the DTP a [DTM_SETMCCOLOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761773%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message.

Answer (score 0):

you can use SendMessage() to disable the windows theme

```
uses
Winapi.CommCtrl,Vcl.Styles,Vcl.Themes,uxTheme;
procedure TForm1.DateTimePicker1DropDown(Sender: TObject);
var hwnd: WinAPI.Windows.HWND;
begin
     hwnd:=SendMessage(TDateTimePicker(Sender).Handle,DTM_GETMONTHCAL,0,0);
     uxTheme.setWindowTheme(hwnd,'','');
end;
```

after the CalColors it works

Result Image

[image]

[Link Youtube Vidéo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lop067EmJ7k)